# Migration Issue: error '80040e14' in ASP classic application from Windows server 2003/SQL Server 2000 to Windows Server 2008 R2/SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, asp-classic, migration

First of all I want you to know that I'm not an engineer, I'm just a web designer working within the constraints of my job. We have a bunch of applications made in ASP classic running in a Windows server 2003 / SQL 2000 environment. The company buy a new server with Windows server 2008R2 and SQL 2012 and they give me the task of migrate the applications to the new server. I read and read a lot of manuals and docs about this for weeks and I fulfilled my task except for one of the apps. The app produces and creates and interface to answer surveys. It is quite strange because the login page works: you put your user name and pass and you enter to the admin area and the options stored in the database shows without problem but when I try to enter to a survey to answer it the browser gives me this:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@errno'.
>
> /SEL/Encuesta/preguntatodo_nuevo.asp, línea 108

Well here is what i found in /SEL/Encuesta/preguntatodo_nuevo.asp, línea 108:

```
sSQL = "Update UsuariosClima set NumCuestContestados = NumCuestContestados+1 Where IDUsuario = " & IDUsuario
conn.Execute(sSQL)
```

I know it's difficult to help me with just this information, so if you need more data please tell me. I don't want you to do my work, if some one can just lead me to the right direction I'll continue by myself. Thank you very very much.

Please remember: I am not an egineer, explain it to me like I was a child.

**UPDATE - Triggers in UsuariosClima:**

**tD_Usuarios:**

```
ALTER trigger tD_Usuarios on dbo.UsuariosClima for DELETE as

begin
declare  @errno   int,
       @errmsg  varchar(255)

if exists (
  select * from deleted,AccesoCuestionarioClima
  where

    AccesoCuestionarioClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario
)
begin
  select @errno  = 30001,
         @errmsg = 'Cannot DELETE "Usuarios" because "AccesoCuestionario" exists.'
  goto error
end

if exists (
  select * from deleted,AccesoClienteClima
  where

    AccesoClienteClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario
)
begin
  select @errno  = 30001,
         @errmsg = 'Cannot DELETE "Usuarios" because "AccesoCliente" exists.'
  goto error
end

if exists (
  select * from deleted,PertenenciaClima
  where

    PertenenciaClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario
)
begin
  select @errno  = 30001,
         @errmsg = 'Cannot DELETE "Usuarios" because "Pertenencia" exists.'
  goto error
end

update RespuestaCuestionariosClima
  set

    RespuestaCuestionariosClima.IDUsuario = NULL
  from RespuestaCuestionariosClima,deleted
  where

    RespuestaCuestionariosClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario

return
error:
raiserror @errno @errmsg
rollback transaction
end
```

**tU_Usuarios:**

```
ALTER trigger tU_Usuarios on dbo.UsuariosClima for UPDATE as
begin
  declare  @numrows int,
       @nullcnt int,
       @validcnt int,
       @insIDUsuario int,
       @errno   int,
       @errmsg  varchar(255)
  select @numrows = @@rowcount

  if

    update(IDUsuario)
  begin
    if exists (
      select * from deleted,AccesoCuestionarioClima
      where

    AccesoCuestionarioClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario
)
begin
  select @errno  = 30005,
         @errmsg = 'Cannot UPDATE "UsuariosClima" because "AccesoCuestionarioClima" exists.'
  goto error
end
  end

  if

update(IDUsuario)
  begin
if exists (
  select * from deleted,AccesoClienteClima
  where

    AccesoClienteClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario
)
begin
  select @errno  = 30005,
         @errmsg = 'Cannot UPDATE "UsuariosClima" because "AccesoClienteClima" exists.'
  goto error
end
  end

  if

update(IDUsuario)
  begin
if exists (
  select * from deleted,PertenenciaClima
  where

    PertenenciaClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario
)
begin
  select @errno  = 30005,
         @errmsg = 'Cannot UPDATE "UsuariosClima" because "PertenenciaClima" exists.'
  goto error
end
  end

  if

update(IDUsuario)
  begin
update RespuestaCuestionariosClima
  set

    RespuestaCuestionariosClima.IDUsuario = NULL
  from RespuestaCuestionariosClima,deleted
  where

    RespuestaCuestionariosClima.IDUsuario = deleted.IDUsuario
end

return
error:
raiserror @errno @errmsg
rollback transaction
end
```

Comment: What is 5 lines above and below that line 108?

Comment: Hi Ghost, I added the lines at the end of the question. Tnanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but are there any triggers on UsuariosClima? The error message indicates @errno was referenced somehow, which doesn't seem to be the case in this code

Comment: with triggers do you mean stored procedures?

Comment: Find @errno in the Stored Procedure dbo.QuitaSeccion I'm checking if it is in other procedures.

Comment: I thought the same thing as Ghost:  sounds like a trigger on the UsuariosClima table.  Triggers are different than stored procedures.  Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190671.aspx

Comment: Wait, sorry, start here instead :)    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178110

Comment: hehe :) I found the trigger and I'm reading the documentation you send me Tom. I just understand the 2% of it :S Will study it. Thanks!

Comment: Added the triggers I found. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the answer provided and my comment beneath it. that should solve error number one. If it works, I would accept the answer provided, edit out your second question here, and post a new one since it is a second different question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, I believe the first error you describe may be nothing more than a syntax error in the call to raiserror in the tU_Usarios trigger. I believe this is being reflected as an error in "Line 108" above because the update is what's causing the error, but the code that calls the RAISERROR bubbles the problem back to the originating statement. When the Update occurs, the trigger fires, an error occurs in the trigger code that is caught, but when control passes to the code that calls RAISERROR, the syntax error arises at "@errno".

I believe the arguments to RAISERROR need to be provided in a comma delimited list, contained within parentheses, etc. And I believe the minimum number of parameters is three - a message id or string, followed by a severity code, and then a state code. Mostly, those last two values end up being something like 16 and 1, respectively.

Comment: Since they are migrating to SQL server 2012, both triggers (The update and the delete) should be changed from `RAISERROR` to `THROW` To do this, he should change the line (in both) to `THROW @errno, @errmsg,2;`

Comment: Thanks guys. Ghost was right, it seems to be working normally! Will do some test to be sure! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I put the answer here to make it more visible. Thanks.

Since they are migrating to SQL server 2012, both triggers (The update and the delete) should be changed from RAISERROR to THROW To do this, he should change the line (in both) to THROW @errno, @errmsg,2; – Ghost

Comment: Wow, take away an accepted answer, post a different answer yourself, and then accept it yourself? Wow. Just wow.